# Are there any ways to check my water for Arsenic?

Tags: arsenic

I've been found to have a large amount of Arsenic in my blood. Is there a way to check my food and water for Arsenic? Are there testing kits available?

Comment: @Gordon California FWIW

Comment: Now that I think about it, you may want to call the county health department where you live. Or go to their office to see if they can help or advise you. Again, if you had the test done in a doctor's office, ask them what you might do.

Comment: I am not giving legal advice here, just giving you some options you might consider.

Comment: Btw you don't mention how many tests you've had. Let a doctor or the health department advise you what other tests you might need to confirm your arsenic level.

Comment: Yes, you can have your water tested, but if you are served by a municipal water supply in California, that's extremely unlikely to be the source. If you have well water, that's a different matter and you should have it tested. Contact your local health agency for guidance. Puzzling out other possible sources is far beyond the scope of this site and falls into the category of personal medical advice, which is squarely off topic here.